# SUM mysqli query returning array

Tags: php, mysqli, sum

What I want is to add up all values in the points column
These are stored as INT(4)

However its echoing Array when I try to display result

```
$pipq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `points` FROM `table` WHERE `result` !='2'");
 $pips = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pipq);
 $sum = 0;
 do {
 $sum += $pips[0];
 } while($pips = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pips));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: rarely seen a `do { } while()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.With SQL query Itself you can do like below:-***

```
$pipq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(`points`) as total_mark FROM `table` WHERE `result` !='2'");
$pips = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pipq);
echo $pips['total_mark'];
```

***2.Your code will work also after below change:-***

```
$pipq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `points` FROM `table` WHERE `result` !='2'");
$sum = 0;
while($pips = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pips)){ // use while only
  $sum += $pips['points']; // use column-name here
}
echo $sum;
```

Note:- 1st one is ***far-better*** than 2nd one. So use 1st one.

Comment: You can directly sum the `points` in mysql query like `SELECT SUM(points) as total_points FROM table WHERE result !='2'`

Comment: @AiyazKhorajia  i am adding that meanwhile you said. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Diamond ! Works perfectly .. will accept answer in 7 mins when system allows me to

Comment: @ChrisYates  check my edited solution once. Glad to help you :):)